# Calculating which $(2^x,2^y)$ coordinates intersect diagonally ($45^{\circ}$) with an arbitrary rectangle in 2D space.

Tags: geometry, power-series

Calculating which $(2^x,2^y)$ coordinates intersect diagonally ($45^{\circ}$) with an arbitrary rectangle in 2D space. The rectangle in this case is your computer monitor.

Consider navigating a 2D space on your computer monitor (the arbitrary rectangle). Let's call the 2D space the $\mathrm{world}$ and your monitor the $\mathrm{viewport}$ where the coordinate system of both the $\mathrm{world}$ and $\mathrm{viewport}$ start at $(1,1)$ at the top left. The $\mathrm{world}$ goes on to infinity.

Let $(ox,oy)$ be the offset between the two such that if $(ox,oy) = (0,0)$, then you would be looking at the top-left of the $\mathrm{world}$ through your $\mathrm{viewport}$. The width and height of the $\mathrm{viewport}$ would determine how much of the world you can see at a given time.

If we want to calculate whether an arbitrary point $(2^x,2^y)$ intersects the $\mathrm{viewport}$ diagonally ($45^{\circ}$), we could do so easily. I want to do the opposite: calculate EACH $(2^x,2^y)$ that intersects diagonally with our viewport.

There are two distinct questions here:

- How can we calculate all intersecting points without the overhead of calculating misses?
- All $(2^x,2^y)$ points above and left of $(ox,oy)$ are easy to conceptualize since our $\mathrm{world}$ starts at $(1,1)$. How can get a mental grasp of points that are below or right of  $(ox,oy)$ since the $\mathrm{world}$ is infinitely large?

**UPDATE:**
To help understand the second point, I generated a high resolution rendering of a $\mathrm{world}$ with a width and height of $10,000$ with diagonals crossing each $(2^x,2^y)$ point. The image can be downloaded [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17859011/Simulation%20Hi-Res.zip) and is essentially a snapshot of your $\mathrm{viewport}$. Due to the size of the image (2MB zipped, 300MB unzipped), I would recommend using Google Picasa as the image viewer.

Sure enough it shows some very interesting patterns but I could not tell if I am missing an infinite number of diagonals that should be intersecting from the right or below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The critical information is already in the equations of the lines given in [this earlier answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184109/calculating-closest-and-furthest-possible-diagonal-intersections).  Let the two corners of your rectangle be $(ox,oy)$ and $(fx,fy)$.  The lines going diagonally up and to the right are lines of constant $x+y$.  The minimum value of $x+y$ in your rectangle is $ox+oy$ and the maximum is $fx+fy$.  So you want all values of $2^x+2^y$ that are in that range.  Similarly, the lines going down to the right are lines of constant $x-y$.  Your minimum $x-y$ is $ox-fy$ and your maximum is $fx-oy$.  You want all values of $2^x-2^y$ that are in that range (which may be negative if $y \gt x).$

Comment: Your TeX messed up in the last line, forgot an ending dollar sign.

Comment: Thank you Ross. I do understand your answer and will be able to use it after a few reads but I have a silly somewhat unrelated question. When I think of lines as a lay man, the only thing that comes to mind is slope. So when you say 'lines of constant $x+y$', I find that hard to visualize. How would you explain this representation to say a child?

Comment: Also, I'd love to hear your explanation to the second point if you get a chance to look at the linked image.

Comment: Lines of constant $x+y$ are those sets of points with a common value.  For example, $(0,10), (1,9), (2,8), \ldots (10,0)$ are on a line of constant $x+y$, in this case $10$.  The constants for your lines are of the form $2^x \pm 2^y$, which is why the lines pack together near $x=\pm y$, because the powers of $2$ are closer together near $0$.

Comment: Ross, I'm not sure if it is appropriate to solicit professional consulting on Stack Exchange. If so, I would highly appreciate a private discussion to see if this would be of any interest to you. The context is, of course, related to the two questions you have answered.

Comment: @EnviousPage:  Thanks.  Fixed.